# jQuery mobile disable page content vertical scroll

Tags: javascript, android, ios, jquery-mobile, scroll

How I can disable vertical content scroll in jquery mobile?
I want disable all scroll for page content.
Thanks.

---

I create jquery.mobile page and in content I add jquery.mobile.scrollview.
When I use scrollview my page content scroll top and bottom. How I can disable scroll content ? My page code:

```
<div id="page2" data-role="page" align="center">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="mydatacontent" class="form">
            <div class="data-table-shadow" data-scroll="y" class="square single-block-view-v" style="height: 750px;">
               <table id="datatable" class="data-table">
                   <tbody id="datatableContent">
                       <!-- Table Data Here -->
                   </tbody>
               </table>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to stop scroll at both direction or just vertically... event.preventDefault will helps you to prevent scroll

Answer (score 14):

I found the answer above to be working well. However, this will prevent scrolling on child-elements of ".ui-content". 
I use the

> *"scrollstart"*

event instead and child elements are still scrollable.

```
$(document).delegate(".ui-content", "scrollstart", false);
```

Tested on iOS6 webview.

Comment: The above method works. But how to revert it back?? i.e. if after making the scroll stop, again if we want to start the scrolling, then what should be done? - Thanks

Comment: @Mak You should then remove the delegated event handler using `.undelegate()`: http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/. If you use `.on()` then you can use `.off()` to remove the event handler. `.live()` has `.die()`, but you should be moving away from `.live()` at this point.

Answer (score 13):

You can bind to the `touchmove` event and `return false` to prevent the default behavior of the `touchmove` event:

```
$(document).delegate('.ui-content', 'touchmove', false);​
```

This should disable scrolling on all `data-role="content"` elements. You can update the `.ui-content` selector to be more specific if you only want this functionality on a/some page(s).

Here is a demo you can try on your mobile device: http://jsfiddle.net/RKXLH/embedded/result/

Comment: Just wanted you to know that there's a *nasty* invisible character at the very end of your snippet. I copy/pasted it to play with and it didn't work. Figured this out only after 15 minutes of struggle.

Comment: @JoãoCunha Interesting, I don't see anything. Might be a difference between the page's character set and the one you're using in your editor application.

Comment: Can confirm, happened to me too in phpstorm on Windows.  Deleting the line and retyping it manually fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

In my experience you have to do this way:

```
var touchScroll = function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
};

$( 'element1').click(function() {
    //this will disable the scroll
    $( this).bind( 'touchmove', touchScroll );

    $( 'element2' ).click(function() {
        //this will enable scrolling
        $( document ).unbind( 'touchmove', touchScroll );
    });
}
```

element1 and element2 can be anything you want, and of course the click function is just for the example, you can choose any function you want.